# the forResource is nil

Tags: swift, bundle, avaudioplayer

The song can play if I hardcode the song file's name instead of "songs[indexPath.row]"

The file is import in the copy bundle resources

```swift
do{
    print(songs[indexPath.row])
    let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: songs[indexPath.row], ofType: "mp3")
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!)
    try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url as URL)
    audioPlayer.play()
} // ...
```

Comment: `The song can play if I hardcode the song file's name instead of "songs[indexPath.row]"`
try to simply `print(songs[indexPath.row])` to see if it matches the "hardcoded filename"

Answer (score 0):

***indexPath.row*** start from 0,1,2...number of rows-1. So check if its match with your songs name just like 0.mp3, 1.mp3, 2.mp3

If not, then rename it like just like this.